# cannot insert same set of values more than once

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, sql-insert

This is my code

```
$isbn = "789";
$author = "mike";
$title = "angular";
$price = 21.2;
$query = "insert into books values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$ps = $db->prepare($query);
$ps->bind_param("sssd",$isbn,$author,$title, $price);
$ps->execute();
echo 'affected rows'. $ps->affected_rows;
$ps->close();
```

This works the first time I execute it.

**The problem**

If I try to execute it multiple times with the same values, then the same values (789, mike, angular, 21.2) are not inserted. No new rows with that values are inserted more than once and the affected_rows is -1.

**Question no. 1**

Is this because I am doing something wrong, or because mySQL prevents duplicates by default?

**Question no. 2**

If this Is a case of default duplicate prevention, how do you turn it off? (Even though I cannot think of any practical use of having the exact same row multiple times, I am curious for both the "default prevention" and the "turn off" part).

Thanks

Comment: You will need to show us the structure of your database to help you here.

Comment: Not shown: Your schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE` is a great way to get this). Your primary key is likely the problem here, you can't introduce duplicate IDs. As a note, doing blind inserts (no columns specified) is a great way to introduce subtle but extremely frustrating bugs. If the column order changes this code is not going to work as expected.